# Select column based on the most recent timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

In the below table, the column "Inverter_1.Eac1" should show value based on the most recent timestamp for that particular day. Every 30 minutes a new data comes in and updates the table. How do I create a view which gives the value of "Inverter_1.Eac1" for a particular day based on the most recent timestamp ?

SQL Table

[image]

Comment: Is there going to be an Inverter_1.Eac2 column?  :-(

Comment: What do you mean by **for a particular day based on the most recent timestamp ?** ?

Comment: Sorry. What I meant is I need the values of Inverter_1.Eac1 for all the days based on the last time stamp. For example if the last time stamp of 24/08/2018 is 6.30 PM, I just need the value of Inverter_1.Eac1 for 24/08/2018 6:30:00

Comment: Could you please add **table and data** in http://sqlfiddle.com/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only `Inverter_1.Eac1` Column

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS
SELECT `Inverter_1.Eac1` FROM 
Table1
WHERE Tstamp IN (SELECT MAX(Tstamp) FROM Table1 GROUP BY SUBSTRING(Tstamp, 1, 10))
```

If you want all Column you can use

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS 
SELECT T1.*
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT Tstamp,`Inverter_1.Eac1` FROM Table1
 WHERE Tstamp IN (SELECT MAX(Tstamp) FROM Table1 GROUP BY SUBSTRING(Tstamp, 1, 10))) AS T2
ON T1.Tstamp=T2.Tstamp AND T1.`Inverter_1.Eac1`=T2.`Inverter_1.Eac1`
```

Comment: When I run your first query, it throws an error saying that Date is not recognized as an inbuilt function. When I remove DATE, the result is wrong and is showing everything.

Comment: Try now i edited the answer i changed date to DATE_FORMAT(Tstamp, '%Y-%m-%d')

Comment: It is giving the same error saying that DATE_FORMAT is not a recognized built in  function name.

Comment: Currently all the variables has nchar. Should I change them first and then run the query ?

Comment: Thanks it works but the data type for the columns are wrong. How do I change it in the same query ?

Comment: You can use `CAST()` Example `CAST(COLUMN_NAME AS DATATYPE)`

Comment: Welcome if you got your answer please accept and upvote